# Return to default error handling

Tags: plugin-development, error, error-handling

In my plugin, I'd like to catch errors when they appear in the control panel, so I can handle them differently. However, from the front-end, I'd like to keep the *default* Craft-style handling of error messages.

```php
try
{
    // Some code which might produce an error
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    if (craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {
        // Do something with $e->getMessage()
    } else {
        // Use default Craft error handling
    }
}
```

All of that is working for me, just trying to sort out how to do this part...

```php
// Use default Craft error handling
```

**How can I get my error handling to just go back to what Craft was doing by default?** I want to make sure my errors still appear in devMode per usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just re-throw the exception and pretend like nothing ever happened...

```
try
{
    // Some code which might produce an error
}
catch (\Exception $e)
{
    if (craft()->request->isCpRequest()) {
        // Do something with $e->getMessage()
    } else {
        // Nothing to see here...
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Brad! Worked like a charm!